# PyCharm doesn't see installed packages

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pytest, virtualenv, requirements

After reimporting the project form VCS I'm trying to install packages listed in requirements.txt. Pycharm installs all packages (also I tried to do it manually; remove requirements.txt and install packages manually, then generate new requirements.txt; etc.). Installation completes successfully and installed packages not highlighted and present in the interpreter settings.
But every time I'm trying to run tests, e.g. `pytest tests/folder/test` I'm getting na error

```
AttributeError: type object 'Test_**' has no attribute 'driver'
```

I suppose fixture which creates driver doesn't initiates\

Sometimes, doing exact the same actions I'm able to run tests successfully, but debugger refuses to work, returning the same error.

Struggling with that already a week, have no idea what to do.

Comment: Can you share the code which you think is causing the error? Also, are you using a virtualenv? Have you considered using Poetry?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that issue was related not to the PyCharm or virtualenv, but to the python 3.11. Revert to the python 3.10 and reinstall of virtualenv solved the problem